# Application first time launch doubts

Tags: iphone, ios

i am having a problem with my application,.i have this code in my mainviewcontroller viewdidload method to check weather the application launch for the first time

```
NSUserDefaults      *padFactoids;
int                 launchCount;

padFactoids = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
launchCount = [padFactoids integerForKey:@"launchCount" ] + 1;
[padFactoids setInteger:launchCount forKey:@"launchCount"];
[padFactoids synchronize];

NSLog(@"number of times: %i this app has been launched", launchCount);

if ( launchCount == 1 )
{

    NSLog(@"this is the FIRST LAUNCH of the myBibleapp");
    // do stuff here as you wish




    UIScrollView_PagingViewController *detailViewController = [[UIScrollView_PagingViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"UIScrollView_PagingViewController" bundle:nil];

    //detailViewController.firstString = firstString;
    // ...
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];

    [detailViewController release];

}
if ( launchCount == 2 )
{
    // do stuff here as you wish

            NSLog(@"this is the SECOND launch of the myBibleapp");
    // do stuff here as you wish

}
```

if the app launch for the first time it will go to the UIScrollView_PagingViewController page,or stay in the mainviewcontroller,my problem is i need to unhide a tick image in the maincontroller to statsfy some conditions  when the app is launched for the first time.that menz `tickimage.hidden = NO;` ,i put this in first condition but i am getting nothing unhide from the code.how to do this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where exactly do you try to unhide the image ? Do you want the image to appear only on first launch ?

Comment: You're gonna have to show the code where & how you place this tickImage of yours into view(controller) hierarchy. if this tickimage is on the mainController, as you say, and you push detailViewController over it, then you won't be able to see tickImage unless you put it in detailViewController

Comment: @rokjarc the tick is the mainviewcontroller the above code also is in mainviewcontroller viewdidload method.i removed the  UIScrollView_PagingViewController from the code and checked but no luck

Comment: You have a problem in where you are trying to hide your image. Can you post your code that you written for hiding your image?

Comment: @R.A its simple i put image.hidden = NO; in the first condition ,again i write to show a alertview in the same condition and it shows the alertview fine.actually my image is hidden by default in XIB

Comment: @stackiphone: but in this code you posted we can't see any reference of you setting up the tickImage or trying to 'unhide' it - do you see this image if you remove the lines where you hide it? One more hint: NSUserDefaults stay on device (or simulator) until you remove the app from it. So between checks what happens at `launchCount == 1` you have to remove the app each time.

Comment: @rokjarc you are right!What if the lastCount exceeds 2?Will he write again a new loop for that or he is need to delete the app and reinstall.

Comment: @stackiphone Ya .I know its simple. But we have to know, did you connect outlet to UiImageview and set an image correctly in it. Try to hide UIImageView(Not an image) that you have.

Comment: @rokjarc i deleted the app and check ,but no luck

Comment: @rokjarc i cant beleve if there is a alertview shows in the same condion and also page redirection occurs in the same condition,why cant i unhide an image in this condition?unbelevable

Comment: @rokjarc thanks for your kind reply,i cheked this in a button clcik of a mainviewcontroller and it hides that image.so there is no problem in it

Comment: This is a bit of a waste of time really as you aren't showing your code that is relevant to the problem you are having. This means that everyone is just going to be left guessing until perhaps through chance someone stumbles across the problem. As I said in my answer, you need to learn some very basic debugging techniques and apply them. How can we know what your problem is if you aren't showing the relevant code and you have made no attempt to check the basics yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to learn how to use breakpoints and debugging techniques in XCode. I suggest you go and read up on them first.....

... Back already? Good. I hope you understand those concepts now. Here's what you need to do

1. Set a breakpoint on `padFactoids = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];`
2. Step through and examine the value of `padFactoids` and `launchCount`.
3. Is `padFactoids` a valid object? Is launchCount the value you expected?
4. If either of these are incorrect, then examine your code to see where you may have gone wrong. Check with the Apple SDK documentation for the methods you are calling.
5. Your app works!

Comment: ,there is no problem in firstlaunch option,it works perfect.but my problem is if i put a image.hidden = NO; it will not take effect on the first launch.

Comment: Well that's a completely different question to what you've just asked. But my answer still stands - learn how to debug your apps. It will save you a lot of time in the future and you will learn a lot.